# Saving data from Summernote div returns empty string

Tags: javascript, express, summernote

I have a Summernote div in which users can enter or edit text. The problem is that I cant find a way to store the text in my db.

My form:

```
<form>
<texarea id = "editor">
</textarea>
</form>
```

I am able to save but it shows me an empty string ('') instead of the text I typed.

Saving to the db:

```
app.post('/upload', isLoggedIn, function (req, res){


        var course = new Upload({
            topic1Content: req.body.topic1Content
        });



        course.save(function (err, course){
            if(err){
                return err;
            }

            console.log(course);
            res.redirect('/profile');
        });


    });
```

Linking Summernote to the textarea:

```
$('#editor').summernote({

                toolbar: [
                    ['style', ['bold', 'italic', 'underline', 'clear']],
                    ['font', ['strikethrough']],
                    ['font-size', ['font-size']],
                    ['color', ['color']],
                    ['para', ['ul', 'ol', 'paragraph']],
                    ['link', ['link']],
                    ['picture', ['picture']],
                    ['group', ['video']],
                    ['table', ['table']]
                ]
                })
```

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136242/textarea-value-change-when-summernote-div-is-changed) on how to link the editor to a `<textarea>` or whatever else. The browser is not sending the text from the editor, it has no reason to, it's not in any form input field.

Comment: I have linked it to the textarea. The problem is that I cannot save the text that is written in the <textarea></textarea> to my db.

Comment: It's not obvious that you've linked it properly, add the relevant code to the question.

Comment: I updated my post with the linking of the textarea to summernote.

Comment: No linkage there. It's not linked to any form input tag. And it's the issue you're experiencing. Look at the answers on the question I've given.

Comment: So how can I link it ?

Comment: [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136242/textarea-value-change-when-summernote-div-is-changed).

Comment: Ok I linked it but it still shows an empty string when I save it. How can I fix this?

Comment: Add the relevant code. We seem to be in a loop :)

Comment: The code you used for linking the editor to the input field.

Comment: That input tag was a mistake. Apologies. I edited my post.

Comment: Still no linkage. Summernote stores its data in a different way, not like a `textarea`, so you need to send data from the editor to `textarea` on form submit, or when user stops typing, or whatever.

Comment: Ohh. Can you post some example code. Thanks for your help!

Comment: We really are in a loop. [See this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136242/textarea-value-change-when-summernote-div-is-changed). More specifically, answers to that question.

Comment: Ok. Then after that?

Comment: Examples are right there.

Comment: No for saving to the db. Should I use the divs name or the inputs name?

Comment: It's too early to think about the DB, you haven't even submitted the editor conents in the form for Express to handle.

Comment: Link the editor to the input field as in any of the answers [to this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22136242/textarea-value-change-when-summernote-div-is-changed).